# Deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm struggling to deserialzer the JSON snippet below due to the different fields being returned, for example in config, it works ok with config.on, as this is in each config block, but as they others are all different, how do I get round this? The JSON returns all the different sensors connected so with different fields.

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
//
foreach (var item in obj)
{
    string temperature = item.ToString();         //this shows the full object in text
    //    Debug.WriteLine(temperature);           //this shows the full object in text

    dynamic group = item;

    string idstring = group.Name.ToString();

    foreach (var prop in group)
    {
        string name = prop.name; 
        string temp = prop.config.on;
        //string temp = prop.state.lastupdated;
        //string temp = prop.swversion;

        //Debug.WriteLine(temp);

        string namestring = name.ToString();
        string tempstring = temp.ToString();

        arr[0] = idstring.ToLower();
        arr[1] = namestring.ToLower();
        arr[2] = tempstring.ToLower();
```

with part of the JSON response

```
{
    "1": {
        "state": {
            "daylight": true,
            "lastupdated": "2017-03-10T07:01:00"
        },
        "config": {
            "on": true,
            "configured": true,
            "sunriseoffset": 30,
            "sunsetoffset": -30
        },
        "name": "Daylight",
        "type": "Daylight",
        "modelid": "PHDL00",
        "manufacturername": "Philips",
        "swversion": "1.0"
    },
    "2": {
        "state": {
            "temperature": 1830,
            "lastupdated": "2017-03-10T08:11:51"
        },
        "config": {
            "on": true,
            "battery": 100,
            "reachable": true,
            "alert": "none",
            "ledindication": false,
            "usertest": false,
            "pending": [

},
"name": "Hall",
"type": "ZLLPresence",
"modelid": "SML001",
"manufacturername": "Philips",
"swversion": "6.1.0.18912",
"uniqueid": "00:17:88:01:02:01:8b:be-02-0406"
  },
 "4": {
    "state": {
  "lightlevel": 12270,
  "dark": true,
  "daylight": false,
  "lastupdated": "2017-03-10T08:14:28"
},
"config": {
  "on": true,
  "battery": 100,
  "reachable": true,
  "alert": "none",
  "tholddark": 16011,
  "tholdoffset": 7000,
  "ledindication": false,
  "usertest": false,
  "pending": [

  ]
},
"name": "Hue ambient light sensor 1",
"type": "ZLLLightLevel",
"modelid": "SML001",
"manufacturername": "Philips",
"swversion": "6.1.0.18912",
"uniqueid": "00:17:88:01:02:01:8b:be-02-0400"
  },
  "5": {
"state": {
  "temperature": 1919,
  "lastupdated": "2017-03-10T08:12:50"
```

Comment: That's not C - did you mean to tag this C#?

Comment: yes ment to be C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to be extra creative with converting missing properties to `String` multiple times. So instead of doing this:

```
string namestring = name.ToString();
string tempstring = temp.ToString();
```

You simply check for `null` condition up front (if you need) and take action accordingly. Json.NET will not throw an exception if a property is missing, so you can try to get all fields that you need and then execute business logic accordingly:

```
string name = prop.name;
string temp = prop.config.on;
string battery = prop.config.battery;
if (battery == null) 
    // maybe throw exception, maybe assign default value; whatever fits you
```

Comment: I'm new and learning C#, how would I assign a default value to the null?

Comment: `if (battery == null)  battery = "myDefaultValue";`

Comment: thanks, works perfect, all fields are populated correctly

Comment: Is there an easy way to ignore the battery value from some sensors and not others? The values are written into a list displayed in a form, but some are duplicate from the same sensor as they split into three tasks per sensor and replicated 3 times

Comment: You could get unique values if that's what you want. But without knowledge of your domain it is hard to guess what needs to be done

Comment: Each sensor has three parts, each part/object has a value "name", but I only want the value name from only one of the objects for example "name": "Hall" and not "name": "ambient light" I've added a bit more JSON in the original question as an example.

Comment: Define `String name = null;` outside of your loops. Then you could just do something like: `if (name == null) name = prop.name;` this way once the value is populated it won't be populated again

Comment: that would work, but the three parts to the sensor all have different names so would still display them all and I only want one of them.

Comment: Based on your code, those values are not displayed anywhere. If you don't want it to be displayed than follow a pattern above.